# Scheduling in Rx .NET

Tags: c#, .net-core, system.reactive

Expected all be executed on the main thread of .NET Core 2.0 console app, so the output being blocked for 10 seconds:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WriteLine($"We are on {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");

        var subject = new Subject<long>();
        var subscription = subject.Subscribe(
            i => WriteLine($"tick on {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}"));

        var timer = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
            .SubscribeOn(Scheduler.CurrentThread)
            .Subscribe(i => subject.OnNext(i));

        Thread.Sleep(10000);
    }
```

Not the case though – a new line comes to console every other second being dispatched by random threads:

> ```
> We are on 1
> tick on 4
> tick on 5
> tick on 4
> tick on 4
> tick on 4
> tick on 4
> tick on 4
> tick on 4
> tick on 5
> ```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Scheduler.CurrentThread` / `CurrentThreadScheduler` will queue items on the same thread that made call to schedule, which will be the thread that the timer happens to run on. Calling `Scheduler.CurrentThread` does not pin the execution of items scheduled via it to the thread that you make the call to `Scheduler.CurrentThread` on but rather the thread that calls `.Schedule()`.

Also, you call `SubscribeOn()` which only affects the thread where the `.Subscribe()` call is going to be made. If you want to control the execution of the item processing, you rather want to call `.ObserveOn()`.

If you want everything to run on the main thread, I suggest running the timer on the main thread, by specifying a scheduler on the interval observable:

```
Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), Scheduler.CurrentThread)
```